# MVC: Is the View allowed to reference mutable elements of the Model without modifying them?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, model

We are developing a board game in Java for a school project and we're having an argument with our tutors on the correct implementation of the MVC pattern (that we are required to use).

In our current implementation the View is subscribed as an Observer to some classes in the model, for example the spaces where the pawns can be placed. This spaces have mutable fields, as you can see in the short example below:

```
public class Space extends Observable {
    private List<Pawn> pawns;
    private Card card;

    // public getters and setters for pawns and card
}
```

It seemed very intuitive for us to give the View direct reference to this class, in this way we can query the Space every frame to retrieve its status (we are using libgdx for the GUI, so we are updating the window every frame).

Now, even though we are not modifying the Model in the View but just calling the getters, our tutor said this approach wasn't acceptable because we *could* modify the Model from the View since we are giving direct reference to mutable objects, and wants us to add a layer of indirection / modify our POJOs in such a way that the View is not able to modify the model.

Could YAGNI be applied to this request? We managed to give the responsibility of modifying the model entirely to the Controller, so I really don't understand why we should change our API just for the reason of restricting access to the Model even though we are not modifying it from the View anyway.

Also, since we are probably going to implement their request, what would be the best approach to complete the task? Making the View see a copy of the model classes so that every modification is pointless? Or maybe creating an interface that only exposes immutable objects to the View?

Thanks in advance for any clarification, we are a bit disoriented by this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, your View layer would only use *immutable objects* — not the same thing as *unmodifiable interfaces* to otherwise mutable objects — with the required info from your models. Such objects would be *tracked* by your Controller and then *copied* to the corresponding View. The MVC pattern can successfully model such scenario.

You will need to add another *layer of indirection* to solve your design problem (and still be MVC compliant). A possible solution follows:

Add a new interface with your view *data model* requirements:

```
/** 
* This interface is adopted by an object that mediates
* the application’s data model for a SpaceView object. 
*/
public interface SpaceViewDataSource {
    List<Pawn> getPawns();
    Card getCard()
    ...
}
```

In your View, store the current data source:

```
public class SpaceView {
    private SpaceViewDataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(SpaceViewDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        reloadData();
        ...
    }

    /** The data source has changed. */
    public void reloadData() { ... } 
    ...
}
```

Finally, your Controller should implement the `SpaceViewDataSource` interface and bind itself as `SpaceView` data source:

```
public class SomeController: SpaceViewDataSource, Observer {
    private SpaceView spaceView;
    private Space spaceModel;

    private void configureSpaceView() {
        spaceView.setDataSource(this);
        spaceModel.addObserver(this);
        ...
    }    

    List<Pawn> getPawns() { /* delegate to spaceModel */ }
    Card getCard() { /* delegate to spaceModel */ }

    void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (o == spaceModel) {
            // A fine grained API may be required if
            // this full reload doesn't perform well.
            spaceView.reloadData();
        }
        ...  
    }
    ...
}
```

In doing so, I added your Controller as a `Space` model *observer* as well.

All these refactorings puts you back on the MVC wagon, buying you:

- a more *reusable* `SpaceView` component (no longer highly coupled with `Space` Model)
- explicitly documented View data model requirements (the `SpaceViewDataSource` interface)
- a View-Model communication that won't bypass the Controller layer
- the Controller tracks the big picture, providing greater flexibility

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So with this additions, every request from the View would be delegated to the Controller, correct? Than the latter just retrieves the info from the Model and forwards the representation to the View. Even though this makes sense, could you be so nice to explain or give reference as why the View would only use immutable objects? I always thought that binding the Model to the View (e.g. with the Observer pattern) would imply having direct reference of the Model in the View.

Comment: @Bit I think you got the overall design right! The communication flows like this: view-controller-model. It may feel a bit convoluted but this is actually MVC in practice ;) Regarding immutable objects...

Comment: @Bit ...generally speaking, *mutability* is evil and should [be avoided as much as possible](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29). Even when using the nice *Observer pattern*, the communication flow is tricky and, in your example, bypasses the Controller layer completely — a central part of the MVC pattern, I may add ;) I recommend the (superb!) **Effective Java** book, by Joshua Bloch, to further explore these issues.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll dig deeper into it.

Comment: @Bit Also: this [Stanford lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j50mPzDMWVQ) provides the *best* MVC introduction that I'm aware of. It's somewhat iOS specific, but highly recommended nevertheless :-)